# How do I maintain aspect ratio of scaled image with max-width?

Tags: media, theming

When I use an Image Style that scales the original image, Drupal 7 (now 7.14) prints the height and width attributes in the img tag whereas before it didn't.
So before, my CSS `img {max-width: 100%;}` preserved the images aspect ratio when displayed in a small box (i.e. on a mobile screen), but now clashes with height and width attributes. Drupal generates enclosing boxes with no explicit height so the result is an elongated distortion.
What can I do - preferably with CSS alone, but in a template file's php if necessary - to preserve the aspect ratio?

Comment: To clarify, this problem started after you upgraded to Drupal 7.14 because img tags now specify height and width attributes?

Comment: For reference, see http://drupal.org/node/1345744

Comment: @JonathanElmore Yes.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's as simple as just adding `height:auto;`

```
img {
max-width:100%;
height:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I haven't tried it but using CSS you might just get away with:

```
img {max-width: 100% !important;}
```

If not, I think the simplest solution would be just to stop the [`theme_image()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme_image/7) function from outputting the width and height attributes (in template.php as you suggest). There are couple of ways you could do this.

Firstly, you could implement `hook_preprocess_image()` to remove the attributes from the theme vars:

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_image(&$variables) {
  foreach (array('width', 'height') as $key) {
    if (isset($variables[$key])) {
      unset($variables[$key]);
    }

    if (isset($variables['attributes'][$key])) {
      unset($variables['attributes'][$key]);
    }
  }
}
```

That method *may* have the potential to be overridden by something else in the system though. To get around that you can simply override the `theme_image()` function altogether (it's not a long function):

```
function MYTHEME_image($variables) {
  $attributes = $variables['attributes'];
  $attributes['src'] = file_create_url($variables['path']);

  // 'width' and 'height' have been removed here
  foreach (array('alt', 'title') as $key) {

    if (isset($variables[$key])) {
      $attributes[$key] = $variables[$key];
    }
  }

  return '<img' . drupal_attributes($attributes) . ' />';
}
```

Comment: I use the `theme_image()` method with good results.

Answer (score 0):

I use this technique for responsive images with fitting into its container (and aligned to whatever point in it) which is also responsive. With this technique you can make miracles. Responsive miracles.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/28073729/1663572